# Declare Mysql variable type outside of procedure

Tags: mysql, ssis

I'm using mysql and writing some queries using SQLYog's query browser. The sql uses a few variables. Below is an example:

```
SELECT NOW() @cur_dt;
SELECT 'table' INTO @tbl;
SELECT DATABASE() INTO @db;
SELECT @@hostname INTO @host;

SELECT @host AS `host`, @db AS `database`, @tbl AS `table`, @cur_date AS `dt`;
```

I'm preparing this sql to be used in SSIS 2005(Sql Server Integration Services) as a source. The issue I'm having is that the variables are coming through as blobs instead of varchars or dates.

I can cast each one which works, but my sql above is just a fraction of what I really need which is a bunch of unions. So in the mean time I'm going to wrap a select around all the unions and cast the fields at that point. I know I could put this in a stored procedure and be done with it but I'm wondering about this exact scenario. My question is if there is a way to specify the variable type when declaring?

Thanks,
GG

PS. If you want to punish a developer make them work with SSIS 2005 and mysql.

Answer (score 0):

How about you select all of your data into a table in the mysql query when you have it accumulated? This will give the data reasonable data types.  Then use SSIS to interact with the table, not the variables per se.

Example:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b059/1

Comment: That would work, but it would be an extra step that I can avoid by wrapping another select and casting like I mention above. What I really need to know is if I can declare a variable's type outside of a procedure.

Comment: Well, I thought you could, but after I tried my first answer based on your feedback, it looks like you can't.  Mysql can be so primitive at times.  Good luck in any case.